# ajax html output does not work like first time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

When the output comes, I click on button the copy of input shows, but it's not perform task like first output?

```
 <body>
 <div>
   <form>

          <input type="text"title="togle">
          <input type="text"title="togle">
          <input type="text"title="togle">

          <input type="button" id="btn1" value="togle">

          <input type="button" id="btn" value="onclick">


   </form>

 </div>
          <div id='show_data'></div>
</body>
```

ajax code function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $("#btn1").click(function() {

       $('[title="togle"]').toggle();

   });
 $("#btn").click(function (event) {
     $.ajax({
        url: "bzu.html",
          success: function (result) {
            $("#show_data").append((result));
        }
    });

  });
});
```

url file

```
<form action="">    
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="togle">
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="onclick">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have in this situation duplicated id "btn1" and "btn" you should probably use class (or any other selector) rather than id. Id must be unique in whole doucument.

Secondly even if you bind to proper class you will bind "once" what means that newly create element will not be bind. Look for a doc: [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). In older JQuery versions there were something like `$(selector).live()` but it is deprecated (>1.7) and removed (>1.9).

One more tip, you can try to use `$(this)` to recognize what element was clicked in your functions.